# WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names

Tags: pm2

i am trying to run create a load balance with nginx and pm 2 but pm 2 keep throwing a warning and stopping the app i have tried reading the docs but nothing is clear
i will greatly appreciate here is my pm 2 config file please help

i am trying to run create a load balance with nginx and pm 2 but pm 2 keep throwing a warning and stopping the app i have tried reading the docs but nothing is clear
i will greatly appreciate here is my pm 2 config file please help

```
module.exports = {
  apps:[
    {
      name: 'vhf_Api_1',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'run start',
      exec_mode: 'fork',
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      env: {
        HOST: '0.0.0.0',
        PORT: 3000,
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
      output: './logs/console_one.log',
      error: './logs/consoleError_one.log',
    },
    {
      name: 'vhf_Api_2',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'run start',
      exec_mode: 'fork',
      autorestart: false,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      // pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
      env: {
        HOST: '0.0.0.0',
        PORT: 3001,
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
      output: './logs/console_two.log',
      error: './logs/consoleError_two.log',
    },
    {
      name: 'vhf_Api_3',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'run start',
      exec_mode: 'fork',
      autorestart: false,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      // pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
      env: {
        HOST: '0.0.0.0',
        PORT: 3002,
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
      output: './logs/console_three.log',
      error: './logs/consoleError2_three.log',
    },
    {
      name: 'vhf_Api_4',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'run start',
      exec_mode: 'fork',
      autorestart: false,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      // pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
      env: {
        HOST: '0.0.0.0',
        PORT: 3003,
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
      output: './logs/console_four.log',
      error: './logs/consoleError2_four.log',
    },  
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 4):

i solved this issue by creating a /config folder in the root directory and a default-0.json file inside of the config folder, the file is empty with just {} with is an empty json object

Comment: It works, but seems like a hack thou